# How to change Modern UI menu text to uppercase

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, modern-ui

I am using `Modern UI` with WPF to create a project. Main menu items appears to be lowercase, which is the one thing on theme I want to change. Is there any way to change it from my project's `MainWindow.xaml` or `MainWindow.xaml.cs` or any other file?

My code for menu is:

```
<mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Home" >
    <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Dashboard" Source="/Pages/home.xaml" />
    </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
</mui:LinkGroup>
```

FYI, I can change it from theme's code and build a new `FirstFloor.ModernUI.dll` file and use it. But that's not what I want, it will not be effective if I cannot override it after using one `.dll`. There must be a way, I must have missed it.

**UPDATE**
I have an image of the display window.

[image]

I do not have problem with `DASHBOARD` but what I want to do is change `home` to uppercase, or how I write on `xaml` code.

Comment: what do you mean by lower case .. don't you provide the text for the headers ?

are you saying that Home is displayed as home and Dashboard as dashboard ?

Comment: yes i am saying the same, i do provide `DisplayName` but it always shows it in lowercase

Comment: This appears to be something inside the `Link` control which is lowercasing everything. You need to create a `Custom Control` that will inherit from `Link` control. You can then **override** or **hide** the `DisplayName` dependency property.

Comment: I agree with Mike , you should look inside Link and search for Display name . see who sets it.

Comment: Can you not expose the style template of the control to look at that binding in place to see if it's not as simple as pulling a converter off the binding base in the template? Like is there a ModernUI.xaml resource dictionary that holds the xaml templates?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the source code for the MUI project there is a theme called **ModernMenu.xaml** (under *Themes* in the *FirstFloor.ModernUI* project).

You can simply add a style to your own application like the following.  (I removed the converter that sets the text to lowercase and increased the spacing between first-line menu options so options that have more than one word are clearly separated from neighbouring options.)

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ModernMenu">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ModernMenu">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="16" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding VisibleLinkGroups}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLinkGroup, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuText}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="23"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Ideal" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,25,0" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                            <TextBlock DataContext="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                               Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                               SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuTextHover}"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuTextSelected}"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListBox>

                    <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedLinkGroup.Links, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLink, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SubMenuText}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,12,0" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                            <Grid DataContext="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Hidden" />
                                            </Grid>

                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SubMenuTextHover}"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SubMenuTextSelected}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

To do this you need a reference to the namespace at the top of your XAML file:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls;assembly=FirstFloor.ModernUI"
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: How to change the style of the LinkGroup.Links?

Comment: Did not work for me. Where exactly do I put this? I'm including the style on my main window but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same problem metioned in the description above.

It seems to be that the `ModernMenu` which contains the links converts the `DisplayName` value to lower case.

With the help of Blend i found out that the basic `ControlTemplate` contains a `TextBlock` with a binding to the `DisplayNameProperty`.

`<TextBlock.Text>
    <Binding Path="DisplayName">
        <Binding.Converter>
            <mui:ToLowerConverter/>
        </Binding.Converter>
    </Binding>
</TextBlock.Text>`

To solve this problem i have created a new `ControlTemplate` for the `ModernMenu` based on the basic `ModernMenu ControlTemplate` but without the `BindingConverter`.
Unfortunately this solution does not work because the whole control is not visible or get not painted when i define a custom `ControlTemplate`.

In my opinion there is no way at the moment to change the the `Style` of the `DisplayNameProperty` easily.. I spent a lot of hours to find a solution for the problem and every try failed in sprout..

Maybe a custom control which inherits from the `ModernMenu` and a new `ControlTemplate` based on the `ModernMenu` without that converter will be work..

I will test it in the next few days and post my experience with this attemp.